# What is the difference between docker.exe and dockercli.exe on Docker Desktop for Windows?

Tags: docker

I am learning about Docker and I have installed Docker for Windows. I am confused by having two command line programs, one is docker.exe (full path: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe) and other is DockerCli.exe (full path: c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe)

Why is there two command line interfaces for Docker? Additionally, there are multiple "version" commands I can invoke. 
When I run `docker version` I get following output:

```
c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Which is different than when I run `docker -v`:

```
c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker>docker -v
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

Finally, when I run `dockercli -Version` I get:

```
c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker>DockerCli.exe -Version

Docker Desktop
Version: 2.0.0.3 (31259)
Channel: stable
Sha1: 8858db33c8692b69de9987a5d672798d778735b2
OS Name: Windows 10 Pro
Windows Edition: Professional
Windows Build Number: 16299
```

Why are there several "version" commands, all with different output?

Answer (score 0):

See next diagram:

[image]

Docker project has upstream project, also downstream product. Anyone or company could develop his own product based on the core parts.

So microsoft together with docker company develop their downstream product on windows 10 called `docker for windows`, it will use `docker ce` as core part.

Then, in short:

**docker.exe**: the docker client provided for user to communicate with docker engine. You can use it to do `docker pull, docker run` etc docker actions.

**dockercli.exe**: the tool provided by docker for windows for user to communicate with docker for windows. You can use it to switch to `linux-container-mode/windows-container-mode` etc.

Additional:

`docker -v` shows the core part that's `Docker CE`'s version while `dockercli.exe -Version` shows the `docker for windows`'s version.